# Bind the controls of HTML5 <audio> tag to custom buttons in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, html5-audio

I have an audio player in my template using the `<audio>` tag, but I would like to use my own styling for the player so  I have the actual native audio player that comes with that tag set to hidden `display: none;`. I then want to bind the controls of the hidden player to my own custom styled player. For example:

```
<audio src="{{recordingUrl}}" #audio></audio>

<!-- other html -->

<button (click)="startPlayer()">/button> <!-- this is my custom play button -->
```

And in my component:

```
@ViewChild("audio", { static: true }) audio: any;
player: any = document.getElementById("audio");


startPlayer(){
    //neither of these work
    this.audio.play();
    this.player.play();
}
```

Is what I am trying to do possible? How can I bind the controls of the `<audio>` tag to my custom buttons?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to wrap the native audio player in an Angular component.

#### Component

```
@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'audio-player',
  template: `
  <audio #audioElement src="{{src}}">
    <p>Your browser does not support HTML5 audio. Here is a <a href="{{src}}">link</a> instead.</p>
  </audio>
  <span (click)="paused ? play() : pause()" class="icon-align-middle">
    <mat-icon *ngIf="paused" class="icon-size-30">play_circle_outline</mat-icon>
    <mat-icon *ngIf="!paused" class="icon-size-30">pause_circle_outline</mat-icon>
  </span>
  `
})
export class AudioPlayerComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @Input() public src: string;
  @Input() public autoplay: boolean = false;
  @Input() public showStateLabel: boolean = false;
  public audioStateLabel = 'Audio sample';
  @Input() public volume: number = 1.0; /* 1.0 is loudest */

  @ViewChild('audioElement', { static: false }) public _audioRef:  ElementRef;
  private audio: HTMLMediaElement;

  public constructor() { }

  public pause(): void {
    if (this.audio) {
      this.audio.pause();
      this.audioStateLabel = 'Paused';
    }
  }

  public get paused(): boolean {
    if (this.audio) {
      return this.audio.paused;
    } else {
      return true;
    }
  }

  public play(): void {
    if (this.audio) {
      if (this.audio.readyState >= 2) {
        this.audio.play();
        this.audioStateLabel = 'Playing...'
      }
    }
  }

  public ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.audio = this._audioRef.nativeElement;
    if (this.audio) {
      this.audio.volume = this.volume;
      this.audio.autoplay = this.autoplay;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `this.audio = this._audioRef.nativeElement;` is what I was ultimately missing. I had gone the route of wrapping in my own component, but was missing that line. Thank you!

Comment: @void See updated answer with the template added inline to the component. To dynamically set the audio source, you would bind a variable as in: `<audio-player *ngIf="audioSampleSrc" src="{{audioSampleSrc}}" showStateLabel=true></audio-player>`.

Comment: This is very useful. Thank you, how can I show the live updated duration while the audio is playing? I would also like to add Angular Material slider to as skeebar. Please help me